# Is it acceptable to use a function return value as a keyword argument default value?

Tags: python, function, arguments

I have a function `plot_variables(xy=var_combinations(), colors=set_colors())` where `var_combinations()` returns some default combinations of variables to be plotted and `set_colors()` returns a dict mapping colors to some herein irrelevant strings. `xy` and `colors` are later used as such:

```
def plot_variables(xy=var_combinations(), colors=set_colors()):
...stuff...   

    for i, (x, y) in enumerate(xy):
            axs1[i].scatter(data[x], data[y], c=data.irrelevant.map(colors))

...stuff...
```

This works as I want - xy and colors can either be left as default, or set manually by passing variables or a dict to `plot_variables()`, but is that the 'best' (or most pythonic) way to set the default values for those kwargs?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes this is fine.

Comment: Great, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You *can* do this but realize that the function being called to create your default value is called exactly once when the primary function is defined. It's not called every time the primary function is invoked. This isn't the clearest way to express your intention.

```
> A = 1
> def foo():
>     print('foo')
>     return A

> def bar(arg=foo()):
>     print(arg)
foo

> bar()
1

> A = 2
> bar()
1
```

More readable,  easier to reason, and (IMO) more pythonic would be something like this:

```
DEFAULT_XY = var_combinations()
DEFAULT_COLORS = set_colors()

def plot_variables(xy=None, colors=None):
    if xy is None:
        xy = DEFAULT_XY
    if colors is None:
        colors = DEFAULT_COLORS
    # ...
```

Comment: That makes more sense, thanks a lot. Should I not be wary of assigning variables in the global scope, though? Edit: I guess I could segment var_combinations() and set_colors() into their own file and create the default vars there, and import that into my main file, yes?

Comment: Be aware but not wary. Global (or module level) constants are fine and appropriate but like all things can be abused.

Comment: Got it. thanks again.